# テスト環境と本番環境を間違えて操作しないようにする方法

Tags: php, サーバー管理

テスト環境と本番環境を間違えて操作しないようにする方法は皆さんどのようにやっていますでしょうか？

下記のようなパターンを大体の方がやっているかと思います。

[テストサイトと本番サイトを間違えてしまわないようにする3つの工夫](https://webtan.impress.co.jp/e/2014/04/08/17289)
[テスト環境と本番環境を見誤らないためのChrome拡張 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/shotets/items/dc7deb01042d700e7ce3)

ただ、httpd.confは操作できないことがある (結構多い)
全員に忘れずに設定させるのは漏れが起きる可能性があるので、
サイト側・サーバー側で設定したい、なと思ってもいます。

アドバイスよろしくお願いします。

Comment: 念のため、今回想定しているのは「Webサイトの環境」周りということでしょうか？(単に サーバ管理 や テスト・本番環境 だと様々なケースが考えられるので) 主にブラウザから何かしらの方法で違いが確認ができれば良い？

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/11380632.html

Answer (score 2):

こんにちは。

本番環境とテスト環境を取り違える問題についてですが、ひとつの回答としては、リリースフローを明確化するということは考えられます。私の関わった以前のPHPプロジェクトではgitを利用して簡便なリリース管理を行っていました。

本番への適用が管理者の操作となり、それ以外の作業はすべてテスト環境やステージングで行われるので不用意な取り違えはなくなります。このあたりは近年自動化なども盛んでホットな分野です。

たとえば、ステージング環境(=本番と同じ環境)を、テスト環境との間に準備し、ステージングから本番へは入念なテスト後、管理者が単純なコピーを行うようにすれば「ついうっかり本番へ」は防ぎやすくなると思います(基本的に本番に作業者はタッチしないため)。

運用環境やリソースも異なると思いますので、望まれた回答にはなっていないかもしれませんが、ノウハウのひとつとしてとらえていただければ幸いです。